# Alexa Developer Console Endpoint Bug

Tags: ssh, alexa-skills-kit

I'm seeing a weird behavior in Alexa developer console whereby a skill with a configured endpoint value:

[image]

uses some old cashed value of the endpoint (note the url difference with the above one in configuration: https://87d44b5e.ngrok.io/kai/api/v1/alexa) leading to a **SKILL_ENDPOINT_ERROR**:

[image]

The configured endpoint (https://87d44b5e.ngrok.io/kai/api/v1/alexa) is perfectly accessible outside Alexa.

The endpoint value referred to in the exception stack of the device log is different: https://simeonleyzerzon5.localhost.run/kai/api/v1/alexa.  I don't know where it originates, but it's a legacy endpoint that I have been using several days ago.  As those values expire several times a day one needs to keep them reconfigured in Alexa dev console.  Seems it has been cached by Alexa somewhere internally.

The skill has account linking enabled.

I tried cleaning browser cookies, restarting the browser, running it in incognito mode, re-saving and re-building model in Alexa json editor, re-saving the correct value  of the endpoint in there, disabling account linking on the dev console, disabling and re-enabling the skill via https://alexa.amazon.com - nothing seems to help.  Same error also persists for me in different browsers.

I shared a skill with a coworker by inviting him via Developer Console's | Setting | User Permissions, and he's able to run the skill without errors and not experiencing that erroneous caching behaviors (his skill uses the newly updated endpoint), whereas for me it continues happening.

- It seems that Alexa saves a skill's snapshot at some point **per user** at which time the endpoint value (perhaps some other values too?) is memorized and then reused, can someone explain when this memorizing is happening and how one can reset that?
- Is above a correct assumption and if so, is that memorization done to prevent a risk of concurrency related problems when a skill is distributed to (via linking) and hit by multiple users?  Or is it intended for something else?
- How does one resolve this erroneous behavior?
- What is the relationship between users and skills and why is the state for a skill shared by several users is not in synch?  How can I trigger a reset and re-synchronization of the skill's state across all users that consume that skill.  What makes it go out of synch?

Comment: Did you managed to solve this?

Comment: are you sure are using the dev veriosn of the skill and not the previous live version?